# Could not obtain "right" stateful session bean in servlet

Tags: jakarta-ee, servlets, jsf-2, jboss, ejb-3.1

First of all: I wish you all Merry Christmas :)

I've got some problem while receiving a stateful session bean in servlet. Simply values that should be set by a JSF are nulls. What I have is a JSF page + one stateful session bean + the temporary Properties bean class + servlet:

First a part of JSF2.0 page:

```
    <h:form id="set_args">
        <h2>Prosze wprowadzic wartosci: (w przyszlosci...)</h2>
        <div class="group">
            <h:outputLabel for="start" value="Wybierz punkt startowy:" />
            <h:inputText id="start" value="#{properties.start}" />
        </div>
        <div class="group">
            <h:outputLabel for="stop" value="Wybierz punkt docelowy:" />
            <h:inputText id="stop" value="#{properties.end}" />
        </div>
        <div class="group">
            <h:commandButton id="start_sim"
                action="#{SimulationBean.setValues()}" value="Rozpocznij" />
        </div>
    </h:form>
```

The Propeties class:

```
import javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped;
import javax.inject.Named;

@RequestScoped
@Named
public class Properties {

private String start;
private String end;

public String getStart() {
    return start;
}

public void setStart(String start) {
    this.start = start;
}

public String getEnd() {
    return end;
}

public void setEnd(String end) {
    this.end = end;
}

}
```

Then an EJB:

```
@Named("SimulationBean")
@Stateful
@SessionScoped
@NamedQueries({ @NamedQuery(name = "findAllJunctions", query = "SELECT j FROM Junction") })
public class SimulationBean implements SimulationBeanLocal {

@Inject
private Properties properties;

private String start;

private String end;

public String getStart() {
    return start;
}

public void setStart(String start) {
    this.start = start;
}

public String getEnd() {
    return end;
}

public void setEnd(String end) {
    this.end = end;
}

public void setValues() {
    this.start = this.properties.getStart();
    this.end = this.properties.getEnd();
    System.out.println("Print VALUES:");
    System.out.println(this.properties.getStart());
    System.out.println(this.properties.getEnd());
}
```

And servlet:

```
@WebServlet("/SimulationServlet")
@EJB(name="SimulationBean", beanInterface = SimulationBeanLocal.class)
public class SimulationServlet extends HttpServlet {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    Context c;
    try {
        c = new InitialContext();
        SimulationBeanLocal bean = (SimulationBeanLocal) c.lookup("java:module/SimulationBean");
```

And when I call the servlet I get a null values in "start" end "end" properties.
Everthing is packed in WAR.

Am I doing something really wrong ?:) I will appreciate any clues.
Thanks.

Comment: Not related to the question: I don't you should use `@NamedQueries` in the SFSB. It's JPA responsibility and `@NamedQueries`/`@NamedQuery` should be used in JPA Entity or Mapped Superclass as described here: [NamedQuery (Java EE 6)](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/NamedQueries.html). Wesołych Świąt :-)

Comment: Yes you, are absolutely right, it is never used and should be throw out, but I simply hadn't done that before posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The servlet is clearly invoked by a different HTTP request than the JSF form submit. As the `Properties` bean is request scoped, every HTTP request will create a new instance and not reuse the instance from previous HTTP requests as you seem to expect. Instead, you need to access the values which are been set in the stateful EJB or some other bean which has a scope broader than the request scope.

But all with all, the whole construct is somewhat odd and confusing. You're mixing several concepts and responsibiities here. Since the functional requirements are not elaborated in the question at all, it's not possible to propose the right approach.

Comment: Thanks a lot for reply,

Firstly I explain what I want to do. 
I want a form in JSF (which I've already have) where you can type Start and End values of something (actually it is a route, but it doesn't matter). Then Inject the Properties class to stateful bean and get that bean (the same bean, where values have been already set) multiple times in a sevlet.

In a SimulationBean class I remember values from the Properties class while the bean is invoked for the first time (the JSF button's action fires "setValues()" method).